# Eclipse GEF graphical editor without header

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am developing RCP plug-in with GEF framework.
I've created basic graphical editor (GraphicalEditor and IEditorInput)

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.openEditor(new TEditorInput("T"), TGraphicalEditor.ID,false);
```

When I run the application I get editor with a header that contains the tab with the name of the editor and control buttons to maximize and minimize the editor.

What I need is to display just the editor, without the header.

Can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with editors is that you can instantiate them multiply for different editor inputs. I am not aware of any way to restrict the number of open editors to just one (well, it appears [you can in Eclipse 4.2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS) if that helps you)

For views, what you want can be done by setting the perspective to fixed and set `showTitle` of the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension to false on the view. Maybe you can use a view instead of an editor and control the editor input yourself?

(For example, using an editor, the default Open action would instantiate a new editor, while you probably want to replace the contents in your only editor, right?)

Comment: Setting perspective to fixed helped a bit. But I can't find showTitle in ViewPart...

Comment: You add it on the `view` element in the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to just hide an editor's tab.

However, you can try two **workarounds**:

- Have your GEF editor be displayed in an Eclipse view instead of an editor and open such a view as a standalone view. An example of how to open a GEF diagram in a view can be found in [GEF's Directed Graph Example](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/reference/digraph1.php). An example of how to open a view as standalone can be found in one the [Eclipse RCP official tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-3/tutorial3.html).
- Extend the *presentation factories*  extension point to control how workbench parts are displayed (which includes control over the part stack tab).

I suggest you try the first approach, as to me it seems easier to implement.

Comment: But as I understand, the "view" looks exactly like the editor (with the problematic header).  
p.s. the example project from your first link can't be imported to the eclipse,it fails while it tries to connect to dev.eclipse.org for authentication (don't know why project of the type "Team Project Set" requires authentication )

Comment: Eclipse views can be opened as *standalone views*. In such mode, they don't have a header. In order to programmatically open a view in standalone mode, in the code of your perspective you. invoke method 'layout.addStandaloneView'.